# Can we lower our unanswered questions number?

Tags: discussion

Right now, Graphic Design has 107 questions that fall in the "Unanswered" category, meaning they have no upvoted answers. About 75 of those *have* answers, they just aren't upvoted. Of course, **they may not be upvoted because they are bad answers**. I'm not suggesting that we upvote answers blindly just to get our unanswered questions number down. I'm suggesting that people check out the questions in the unanswered tab and see if any of those answers are solid and have slipped under your radar.

- [Here are unanswered questions, sorted with the newest ones first.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest)
- [Here are unanswered questions, sorted by most to least votes.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes)
- [Here are questions with no answers. Do you know the answer?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers)

And honestly, 107 unanswered questions isn't too shabby, nor is it indicative of a big problem. I just think that the number could possibly be even lower if you, our awesome users, make sure that those answers do/do not deserve votes.

Comment: As of Nov 09, 2017 that number has go up almost 2000% - 2,016